# How to open .trk file in xtk from an HTML link

Tags: javascript, xtk

Does anybody have an example of how to display a .trk file in xtk by sending the filename through HTML link to a javascript function containing xtk code? So basically

1. have some HTML href elements that call javascript containing xtk code sending the .trk file location
2. when the user clicks the link, xtk displays the .trk file in a popup window

I am new to xtk and all the examples they provide have the filename hardcoded in js files. I tried tweaking the code to get the filename as javascript function parameter, but it does not work. Any pointer is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple demo which might solve your #1 issue:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="showFiber('http://x.babymri.org/?cctracks.trk');">Render Fiber</a>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7Sk4v/

My 2 cts